# Change destination speakers of Windows Media Player

Tags: c#

We're using an embedded AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer to play various audio 
files in our application (C# code). I'd like to change, programmatically, 
the destination speakers (output audio device). I can't find any code to 
accomplish this. I've searched high and low. Nothing tells me how to select 
and/or change the speakers for audio output. Yet the standard Windows Media 
Player in Windows XP certainly can change audio devices quite readily via 
Tools / Options.

(I don't want to change the default sound card, only to change it for the this instance of WMP)

Can someone show me the light on how to change speakers, in C# code?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am aware, the WMP control does not have this capability. You may want to consider using some third-party Media libraries, depending on the type of media you want to use. If you only need to play audio files, you can try the **Bass libraries - www.un4seen.com**.
If you need video capability as well, you may have to use DirectShow. There is a library with samples available [here](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/). If you want to use WPF as your view engine, there is a great media library called **WPF Media Kit**, which is available on CodePlex [here](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/).